# Where does the automatically generated file #hello.ml# for hello.ml come from?

Tags: emacs, merlin

I am working on a file called `hello.ml` in Ocaml under emacs Taureg Merlin mode, and I realize there's file `#hello.ml#` (not `hellocaml.ml~`) in the same directory. I have only used the toplevel with `#use "hello.ml"` and called `ocamlbuild` during the time. The file `#hello.ml#` seems to be just a plain text snapshot of `hello.ml` at some point. I tried to update `hello.ml` and use `#use` in toplevel again, but `#hello.ml#` is not in sync with `hello.ml`. Does anyone have an idea where this file comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [auto-save file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html#Auto-Save-Files) from Emacs. It only exists when you have unsaved changes in Emacs. Thanks to this file, in case your computer (or just Emacs) crashes with unsaved changes, Emacs can restore the unsaved changes when you restart and open the file again.

(I'm describing the default behavior, see the manual for how to configure it.)

Comment: So what's the difference between this file and `hello.ml~`? I thought it was the auto-save file that serves the purpose you said...

Comment: @kumom `hello.ml~` is a backup file. It's a previous version of the file from before the last time you saved. `#hello.ml#` is the current version from after the last time you saved.